# How to get image source from table cell when click on respective column header in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a admin panel in which I want to sort table base on clicked table header, means If I click on Email then table is sort based on email id. It is working fine. I have develop this sorting functionality using jQuery. Here is my code for sorting.

```
function sortTable(f, n) {
        var rows = $('#dataTables-example tbody  tr').get();
        rows.sort(function (a, b) {
            var A = getVal(a);
            var B = getVal(b);
            if (A < B) {
                return -1 * f;
            }
            if (A > B) {
                return 1 * f;
            }
            return 0;
        });
        function getVal(elm) {
            console.log($(elm).parent().index());
            var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
            if ($.isNumeric(v)) {
                v = parseInt(v, 10);
            }
            return v;
        }
        $.each(rows, function (index, row) {
            $('#dataTables-example').children('tbody').append(row);
        });
    }
    var f_sl = 1;
    var f_nm = 1;
    $("#email").click(function () {
        f_sl *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_sl, n);
    });
    $("#publish").click(function () {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm, n);
    });
```

In publish column I user image to display publish or unpublish. Based on image name i want to sort table as I can sort using email. So can you please guide me how can i do this???

I want to know how to get image path or name when i click on table header cell of respective column.

Comment: What do you have in the image column, Absolute path to image or the image name?

Comment: I have absolute path to image

Comment: so you want to sort the table with file name for the these images?

Comment: Yes . I have two images "publish.png" and "unpublish.png" So I want to sort table base on image name.

Comment: this is a bit late but for the future viewers may be this can help <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367872/how-to-get-images-from-a-table-with-other-column-texts-using-php>